# JSON.Stringify giving too much information

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm pulling data from an API using a simple fetch call. The API call pulls an object and I'm using `JSON.Stringify` to extract the data in readable format, however, I just want the number that it produces. Here is an excerpt from the API:

```json
{
  "confirmed": {
    "value": 24637475,
    "detail": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/confirmed"
  },
  "recovered": {
    "value": 16108272,
    "detail": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/recovered"
  },
```

I'm just trying to get the `confirmed.value`.

Here is my current code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Cards = () => {
    const [hasError, setErrors] = useState(false);
    const [data, setData] = useState({});

    async function fetchData() {
        const res = await fetch("https://covid19.mathdro.id/api");
        res
            .json()
            .then(res => setData(res))
            .catch(err => setErrors(err));
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <span>{JSON.stringify(data.confirmed)}</span>
            <hr />
            <span>Has error: {JSON.stringify(hasError)}</span>
        </div>
    );
};
export default Cards;
```

Comment: Doesn't `data.confirmed && data.confirmed.value` give you what you need?

Comment: @keikai A string can't have a property `confirmed`

Comment: @charlietfl  both of those give me undefined

Comment: right...on first render, but what about after data is loaded?

Comment: @charlietfl ```"value":24649431,"detail":"https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/confirmed"}```

Comment: Ok...that's the stringified output, so wrap what's in my first comment in `{}` and try that. No stringify needed. You have to account for data not arriving until after first render occurs

Comment: @charlietfl still gives me that 'value' is undefined. using both ```data.confirmed``` as well as ```data.confirmed.value```

Comment: And that is when you don't use stringify?

Comment: @charlietfl correct. I've never done this without using a ton of hooks to accomplish it. But all I wanted to do was show the value inside 'confirmed' but to answer your question I use ```<span>{data.confirmed.value}</span>```

Comment: Ok...and that will definitely be undefined first render since default object doesn't have the nested properties. Won't be defined until after the fetch completes and updates state

Comment: @charlietfl any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Not really . Not making sense you can get the stringified version to show but not the object version. Create a demo that reproduces it

Comment: @charlietfl I actually ended up scapping it and just rewriting it after a good sip of coffee and I got it working, answer is above.

Comment: Yeah, if that's all you ever use from the request, much cleaner

Comment: @charlietfl what if I wanted to put the API call in another folder and call it in different places? Just to make the code look simpler?

Comment: You mean like import a function that returns the request promise?

Comment: @charlietfl yes, just sticking the API call in another folder and calling it with a useEffect.

Comment: Do some searching around on how to create custom async hooks. Can build one with useeffect right in it and simply import that custom hook

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring this out after taking a second to look it over and just refactoring it.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Cards = () => {
    const [confirmed, setConfirmed] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://covid19.mathdro.id/api")
            .then((responseData) => responseData.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setConfirmed(data.confirmed.value)
            })
    })


    return (
        <div>
            {confirmed}
        </div>
    );
};
export default Cards;
```

I just put everything in the useEffect and that ended up solving my problem. I'm not really sure why that was the solution.

Comment: Even this is wrong it will run on every render . Better way to check is this `data && {renderComponent}` whatever data component you want to show